# Register custom python function in QGIS Server 3.10

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-server

I have some custom python functions I have defined in QGIS which I use in print composer. I tried copying the python folder into the QGIS Server path but they do not get propagated. I have seen the following http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Custom-python-expressions-in-QGIS-Server-td5362875.html but the answer seems vague to me. Any hints / documentation or  that I could read on this anyone out there with an example that I could look at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried quickly by writing a quick QGIS Server plugin and it worked. I have followed the link you gave more or less.

1. Make a folder called `ServerExpression` for instance.
2. In this folder, add a quick `metadata.txt`:

   ```
    [general]
    name=Server expression
    description=Expose Python expressions on QGIS Server
    about=Expose Python expressions on QGIS Server
    version=1.0
    qgisMinimumVersion=3.4
    author=Etienne Trimaille
    email=etrimaille@3liz.com
    server=True
   ```
3. In this folder, add a `__init__.py`:

   ```
    from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog, Qgis, QgsExpression
    from qgis.utils import qgsfunction

    @qgsfunction(
        args='auto', group='Your group', usesGeometry=False, referencedColumns=[], helpText='Define the help string here')
    def your_expression(params, feature, parent):
        # UPDATE the qgsfunction above
        # ADD HERE THE EXPRESSION CODE THAT YOU WROTE IN QGIS.
        return params.upper()

    class ServerExpressionPlugin:
        def __init__(self):
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Loading expressions', 'ServerExpression', Qgis.Info)
            QgsExpression.registerFunction(your_expression)

    def serverClassFactory(serverIface):
        _ = serverIface
        return ServerExpressionPlugin()
   ```
4. Transfer this folder in the plugin directory on the server, reload QGIS Server if needed
5. If in your layout, you have a label with

   ```
    [%your_expression('hello')%]
   ```

You will have a PDF with `HELLO`.

To make things easy, I have added all the code in the `__init__.py`. Of course, you can make your Python files listing your expressions, to make it easier to copy paste between Desktop and Server.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I am using docker to run qgis server. Yes the 3liz docker container

Comment: I have created the server plugin in QGIS plugin path but the functions do not get registered. I am using 3liz/qgis-map-server:3.10

Comment: Do you have any server plugin already which are working?

Comment: @etrimaille, THANKS a lot ... you saved my day with this answer! Now I have a full functional QGIS 3.16 server on Windows 2016 serving beautiful wavy, wiggly lines - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376411/custom-qgis-linestyle-expression-function-wont-work-with-multilinestrings/376503#376503 ... I owe you a BIG beer!