# Custom QGIS linestyle expression function won't work with MultiLineStrings

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, line, style

After my experiences with a custom Python linestyle expression function ([Wavy Edge on polygon in QGIS using geometry generators](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367422/wavy-edge-on-polygon-in-qgis-using-geometry-generators/370227#370227)) I modified the code to support *Polygons* with holes, *MultiPolygons* and *MultiLineStrings* as well. See the following picture using the same Geometry generator styling for all layer types:

> smooth(customLineStyle( $geometry,'45 30,45 0,45 -30,45 0'),5)

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, QGIS crashes with *MultiLineStrings* in Windows 10 (QGIS 3.14.16-Pi).

I don't know, is it a bug or is there something wrong with my code (see below)?

```py
import itertools, math, re
from qgis.core import qgsfunction,QgsPoint,QgsGeometry,QgsWkbTypes,QgsPointXY

def createCustomLine(geom,param):
    geom = QgsGeometry(geom)
    dst = geom.length()
    vertices = geom.asPolyline()
    start = (vertices[0].x(),vertices[0].y())
    end = (vertices[-1].x(),vertices[-1].y())
    l = [list(map(float,x.split(' '))) for x in param.split(',')]
    steps,offsets = zip(*l)
    d = sum(steps)
    newdst = dst / int(dst / d)
    newsteps = [x / d  * newdst for x in steps]
    d = sum(newsteps)
    cnt = int(dst / d)
    distances = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(newsteps,cnt)))[0:-1]
    alloffsets = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(offsets,cnt)))
    alloffsets.insert(0,0)
    distances = list(itertools.accumulate(distances))
    points2d = [(lambda g,d: (g.x(), g.y(),d))(geom.interpolate(d).asPoint(),d) for d in distances]
    distances.insert(0,0)
    points2d.insert(0,start) # prepend start point
    points = [QgsPoint(start[0],start[1])]
    for i,pt in enumerate(points2d[1:]):
        if distances[i+1] > distances[i]:
            corrAngle = -90
        else:
            corrAngle = 90
        qgsPt = QgsPoint(pt[0],pt[1])
        points.append(qgsPt.project(alloffsets[i+1],QgsPoint(points2d[i][0],points2d[i][1]).azimuth(qgsPt) + corrAngle))

    points.append(QgsPoint(end[0],end[1])) # append end point
    return QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points)

def createCustomPolygon(geom,param):
    wkt = geom.asWkt()
    geometries = [QgsGeometry.fromWkt('LineString(%s)' % g) for g in re.findall('[^()]+',wkt) if g != ','][1:]
    geom = geometries[0]
    rings = geometries[1:]
    geom = createCustomLine(geom,param)
    geom = geom.convertToType(QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
    if rings:
        for ring in rings:
            ring = createCustomLine(ring,param)
            ptArray = [QgsPointXY(pt.x(),pt.y()) for pt in list(ring.vertices())]
            geom.addRing(ptArray)
    return geom
    
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False, referencedColumns=[])
def customLineStyle(geom,param,feature,parent):
    rings = None
    if geom.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineString:
        newGeom = createCustomLine(geom,param)
    elif geom.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.MultiLineString:
        wkt = "MultiLineString("+",".join([re.findall('^[^(]+(.+)',createCustomLine(part,param).asWkt())[0] for part in geom.parts()])+")"
        newGeom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt)
    elif geom.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.Polygon:
        newGeom = createCustomPolygon(geom,param)
    elif geom.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.MultiPolygon:
        wkt = "MultiPolygon("+",".join([re.findall('^[^(]+(.+)',createCustomPolygon(part,param).asWkt())[0] for part in geom.parts()])+")"
        newGeom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt)
      
    return newGeom
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of changes in my terrible inefficient code, it's now working with all geometry types. I could add some caching to make it a little bit faster, but for the moment it's ok.

```py
import itertools, math, re
from qgis.core import qgsfunction,QgsGeometry,QgsWkbTypes,QgsPointXY

def createCustomLine(vertices,param):
    geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(vertices)
    dst = geom.length()
    start = (vertices[0].x(),vertices[0].y())
    end = (vertices[-1].x(),vertices[-1].y())
    l = [list(map(float,x.split(' '))) for x in param.split(',')]
    steps,offsets = zip(*l)
    d = sum(steps)
    newdst = dst / int(dst / d)
    newsteps = [x / d  * newdst for x in steps]
    d = sum(newsteps)
    cnt = int(dst / d)
    distances = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(newsteps,cnt)))[0:-1]
    alloffsets = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(offsets,cnt)))
    alloffsets.insert(0,0)
    distances = list(itertools.accumulate(distances))
    points2d = [(lambda g,d: (g.x(), g.y(),d))(geom.interpolate(d).asPoint(),d) for d in distances]
    distances.insert(0,0)
    points2d.insert(0,start) # prepend start point
    points = [QgsPointXY(start[0],start[1])]
    for i,pt in enumerate(points2d[1:]):
        if distances[i+1] > distances[i]:
            corrAngle = -90
        else:
            corrAngle = 90
        qgsPt = QgsPointXY(pt[0],pt[1])
        points.append(qgsPt.project(alloffsets[i+1],QgsPointXY(points2d[i][0],points2d[i][1]).azimuth(qgsPt) + corrAngle))

    points.append(QgsPointXY(end[0],end[1])) # append end point
    return points

def createCustomPolygon(geom,param):
    if not geom.isMultipart():
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([createCustomLine(ring,param) for ring in geom.asPolygon()])
    else:
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolygonXY([[createCustomLine(ring,param) for ring in polyg] for polyg in geom.asMultiPolygon()])

    return geom
    
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False, referencedColumns=[])
def customLineStyle(geom,param,feature,parent):
    """
    <style>
    span { color: red }

    </style>
    <h2>apply a custom linestyle to a (multi)linestring or (multi)polygon</h2>

    customLineStyle(<span>geometry</span>,<span>param</span>)<br/>

    <table>
        <tr><td><span>geometry</span></td><td>linestring geometry</td></tr>
        <tr><td><span>param</span></td><td>list of linear point distances followed by perpendicular offsets</tr>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    Example:
    <img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="55.471mm" height="29.561mm" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 436.78 232.76" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 -147.87 -50.91)" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="22.917" font-weight="400" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel"><rect width="787" height="394"/></g><g fill="none" font-size="22.917" font-weight="400" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel"><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 -147.87 -50.91)" stroke="#c40000" stroke-width="5.5118"><path d="m169.4 223.02 103.14-58.768 206.27 117.54 103.14-58.768" fill-rule="evenodd"/></g><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 -147.87 -50.91)" stroke="#5d5d5d" stroke-dasharray="78.7402, 31.4961" stroke-width="2.0472"><path d="m169.4 223.02h412.54" fill-rule="evenodd"/></g><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 -147.87 -50.91)"><path d="m272.8 164.31 1.058 58.707" fill-rule="evenodd" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></g></g><g font-size="22.917" font-weight="400" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel"><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 -147.87 -50.91)" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="m335.78 163.17-11.596 12.022 11.022-0.199 0.632 35.09-11.022 0.198 12.022 11.597 11.596-12.022-11.021 0.198-0.633-35.089 11.022-0.199-12.022-11.596" fill-rule="evenodd"/></g><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 -147.87 -50.91)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000000"><path d="m351.52 162.89-78.728 1.419" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="m352.58 221.6-78.728 1.418" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></g><g><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 227.13 140.57)" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="m-8.2374-47.064c3.7445-0.0675 6.5367 0.9234 8.3767 2.9726 1.5291 1.712 2.3162 3.8183 2.3613 6.3188 0.05009 2.7799-0.81972 5.0684-2.6094 6.8655-1.7897 1.7972-4.2902 2.7248-7.5016 2.7826-2.6022 0.0469-4.656-0.3065-6.1615-1.0603s-2.6843-1.8689-3.5362-3.3455-1.2938-3.0971-1.3256-4.8615c-0.051-2.8306 0.8154-5.1349 2.5991-6.9129 1.7836-1.778 4.3827-2.6978 7.7972-2.7593m0.06347 3.5224c-2.5894 0.0466-4.5182 0.6464-5.7862 1.7993s-1.8865 2.5862-1.8557 4.2998c0.0307 1.7009 0.7035 3.1045 2.0186 4.2109 1.3151 1.1063 3.299 1.6356 5.9519 1.5878 2.5006-0.045 4.3848-0.6472 5.6527-1.8064 1.2679-1.1593 1.8866-2.583 1.8562-4.2712-0.030876-1.7136-0.6975-3.1237-1.9999-4.2303-1.3024-1.1066-3.2483-1.6366-5.8377-1.5899m-9.7396 20.751 17.555-0.3163-0.054546-3.0274 2.6656-0.048 0.05455 3.0273 2.1515-0.0387c1.3582-0.0245 2.3695 0.0779 3.0339 0.3072 0.89448 0.314 1.6253 0.8817 2.1924 1.7032 0.56716 0.8214 0.86416 1.9811 0.89116 3.4789 0.0174 0.9647-0.0776 2.033-0.2851 3.2049l-2.9985-0.4603c0.11412-0.7131 0.16547-1.387 0.15403-2.0216-0.01875-1.0409-0.25415-1.7731-0.70619-2.1966-0.45204-0.4236-1.2873-0.6244-2.5059-0.6024l-1.8659 0.0336 0.07102 3.9412-2.6656 0.0481-0.071014-3.9413-17.555 0.3163-0.0614-3.4081m0.1982 10.998 17.555-0.3163-0.054547-3.0274 2.6656-0.048 0.05454 3.0273 2.1515-0.0387c1.3582-0.0245 2.3695 0.0779 3.0339 0.3072 0.89447 0.314 1.6253 0.8817 2.1924 1.7032 0.5671 0.82146 0.8642 1.9811 0.8912 3.4789 0.0174 0.96469-0.0777 2.033-0.2851 3.2049l-2.9985-0.46021c0.11413-0.71311 0.16547-1.387 0.15404-2.0217-0.01876-1.0408-0.25415-1.773-0.70619-2.1966s-1.2873-0.62437-2.5059-0.60241l-1.8659 0.03362 0.07101 3.9412-2.6656 0.04803-0.071014-3.9413-17.555 0.31631-0.0614-3.4081m6.2123 9.6997 0.5942 3.3795c-1.3547 0.21487-2.386 0.76356-3.0939 1.6461-0.7078 0.88252-1.0477 2.1044-1.0195 3.6657 0.0283 1.574 0.3699 2.736 1.0246 3.486 0.6547 0.75 1.4137 1.1173 2.2768 1.1017 0.7743-0.0139 1.3775-0.3613 1.8096-1.042 0.29618-0.47516 0.66228-1.6499 1.0983-3.5243 0.58938-2.5247 1.107-4.2767 1.5528-5.2561 0.44581-0.97938 1.0736-1.7271 1.8832-2.2433 0.80968-0.51614 1.7096-0.78312 2.6996-0.80096 0.90122-0.01623 1.7395 0.17499 2.5149 0.57369 0.77538 0.39869 1.4233 0.94888 1.9439 1.6505 0.4031 0.52603 0.74939 1.2467 1.0389 2.1621 0.28949 0.91535 0.44372 1.8998 0.46271 2.9533 0.02858 1.5867-0.17479 2.9839-0.61014 4.1916-0.43534 1.2077-1.0382 2.1042-1.8085 2.6895-0.77034 0.5852-1.8073 0.9975-3.1108 1.2369l-0.51733-3.3428c1.0381-0.1711 1.8425-0.6268 2.4133-1.3672s0.8441-1.777 0.82009-3.1098c-0.02836-1.574-0.30881-2.6926-0.84136-3.356-0.53254-0.66337-1.1479-0.98876-1.846-0.97618-0.44427 8e-3 -0.84159 0.15483-1.192 0.44049-0.36307 0.28588-0.65982 0.72929-0.89024 1.3302-0.12076 0.345-0.39452 1.3594-0.82129 3.0431-0.60367 2.4361-1.1031 4.137-1.4984 5.1028-0.39527 0.9658-0.98147 1.7286-1.7586 2.2886s-1.7496 0.8505-2.9174 0.8716c-1.1424 0.0206-2.2241-0.2932-3.2452-0.9415-1.0212-0.6482-1.8191-1.5956-2.3939-2.8423-0.5748-1.2467-0.8765-2.6634-0.9051-4.25-0.0473-2.6275 0.4624-4.6397 1.5292-6.0366 1.0668-1.3969 2.6693-2.3051 4.8076-2.7245m1.0924 34.201-0.3741 3.5493c-2.079-0.5212-3.7034-1.5268-4.873-3.0167s-1.7756-3.409-1.8179-5.7572c-0.0533-2.9576 0.8152-5.3191 2.6055-7.0845 1.7903-1.7655 4.3292-2.6778 7.6167-2.737 3.4018-0.0613 6.0578 0.7669 7.9679 2.4848 1.9102 1.7178 2.8904 3.9729 2.9407 6.7655 0.04871 2.7036-0.83175 4.9288-2.6414 6.6756-1.8096 1.7467-4.3836 2.6502-7.722 2.7103-0.20309 0.0037-0.50784 0.0028-0.91425-0.0025l-0.27171-15.08c-2.219 0.1669-3.9086 0.8259-5.0688 1.9769-1.1601 1.1509-1.7249 2.5705-1.6945 4.2587 0.0226 1.2566 0.372 2.3233 1.048 3.1999 0.6761 0.8767 1.7423 1.5621 3.1987 2.0565m5.3379-11.352 0.20343 11.291c1.6982-0.1829 2.966-0.6375 3.8037-1.3636 1.3004-1.1154 1.935-2.5426 1.9036-4.2816-0.02836-1.574-0.57897-2.8877-1.6518-3.9413-1.0729-1.0536-2.4925-1.6217-4.2589-1.7041m-8.5023 27.052-3.0185 0.5496c-0.2204-0.961-0.3375-1.8224-0.3513-2.584-0.0224-1.2439 0.157-2.2121 0.5381-2.9046 0.3812-0.6926 0.8897-1.1842 1.5257-1.475s1.9821-0.4548 4.0384-0.4918l11.633-0.2096-0.045284-2.5133 2.6656-0.048 0.04528 2.5132 5.0075-0.0902 2.1177 3.3711-7.0638 0.1273 0.06209 3.4462-2.6656 0.048-0.062094-3.4462-11.824 0.2131c-0.9774 0.0176-1.6047 0.0892-1.8817 0.2148-0.2771 0.1256-0.4957 0.3264-0.6558 0.6022-0.1601 0.2759-0.2356 0.6677-0.2264 1.1755 0.0068 0.3807 0.0603 0.8813 0.1604 1.5017" fill-rule="evenodd"/></g><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 -147.87 -50.91)" fill="none"><path d="m168.08 163.78h104.46" fill-rule="evenodd" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></g><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 -147.87 -50.91)" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="m168.08 100.79 11.811 11.811v-11.024h80.835v11.024l11.811-11.811-11.811-11.811v11.023h-80.835v-11.023l-11.811 11.811" fill-rule="evenodd"/></g></g><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 -147.87 -50.91)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000000"><path d="m168.08 85.04v78.74" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="m272.53 85.04v78.74" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></g><g transform="matrix(.99822 0 0 .99822 72.039 10.398)" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="m-57.809 17.5v-2.5518c-1.2822 2.0059-3.1675 3.0088-5.6558 3.0088-1.6123 0-3.0944-0.4443-4.4465-1.333-1.352-0.8887-2.3994-2.1296-3.1421-3.7229s-1.114-3.4246-1.114-5.4939c0-2.0186 0.3364-3.8498 1.0093-5.4939 0.6728-1.644 1.6821-2.9041 3.0278-3.78 1.3457-0.87598 2.8501-1.314 4.5132-1.314 1.2188 0 2.3042 0.25708 3.2563 0.77124 0.9522 0.51416 1.7266 1.1838 2.3233 2.009v-10.017h3.4087v27.917h-3.1802m-10.835-10.093c0 2.5898 0.5459 4.5259 1.6377 5.8081 1.0917 1.2822 2.3803 1.9234 3.8657 1.9234 1.498 0 2.7707-0.6126 3.8181-1.8377s1.571-3.0945 1.571-5.6081c0-2.7676-0.5332-4.7988-1.5996-6.0938-1.0664-1.2949-2.3803-1.9424-3.9419-1.9424-1.5234 0-2.7961 0.62207-3.8181 1.8662-1.022 1.2441-1.5329 3.2056-1.5329 5.8843m19.734-13.882v-3.9419h3.4278v3.9419h-3.4278m0 23.975v-20.224h3.4278v20.224h-3.4278m7.6099-6.0366 3.3897-0.5332c0.1904 1.3584 0.7204 2.3994 1.59 3.123 0.8697 0.7236 2.0852 1.0855 3.6468 1.0855 1.5742 0 2.7422-0.3206 3.5039-0.9617s1.1426-1.3933 1.1426-2.2566c0-0.7744-0.3365-1.3838-1.0093-1.8281-0.4697-0.30471-1.6377-0.69191-3.5039-1.1616-2.5137-0.63477-4.2561-1.1838-5.2273-1.6472s-1.7075-1.1045-2.209-1.9233-0.7522-1.7234-0.7522-2.7136c0-0.90137 0.2063-1.7361 0.6189-2.5042 0.4126-0.76807 0.9744-1.406 1.6853-1.9138 0.5332-0.39356 1.26-0.72681 2.1804-0.99976s1.9075-0.40942 2.9612-0.40942c1.5869 0 2.9802 0.22852 4.1799 0.68555s2.0852 1.0759 2.6565 1.8567c0.5713 0.78076 0.9649 1.825 1.1807 3.1326l-3.3516 0.45703c-0.1523-1.041-0.5935-1.8535-1.3235-2.4375-0.7299-0.58398-1.7614-0.87598-3.0944-0.87598-1.5743 0-2.6978 0.26025-3.3707 0.78076-0.6728 0.52051-1.0092 1.1299-1.0092 1.8281 0 0.44433 0.1396 0.84423 0.4189 1.1997 0.2793 0.36817 0.7173 0.67285 1.314 0.91407 0.3428 0.12695 1.352 0.41894 3.0278 0.87597 2.4248 0.64746 4.1165 1.1775 5.075 1.5901s1.7107 1.0124 2.2566 1.7996 0.8188 1.7646 0.8188 2.9326c0 1.1426-0.3332 2.2185-0.9998 3.2278-0.6665 1.0092-1.6281 1.79-2.885 2.3423-1.2568 0.5522-2.6787 0.8283-4.2656 0.8283-2.6279 0-4.6306-0.5459-6.008-1.6377-1.3775-1.0918-2.2566-2.7104-2.6375-4.8559m27.855 2.9707 0.4951 3.0278c-0.9648 0.2031-1.8281 0.3047-2.5898 0.3047-1.2442 0-2.209-0.1968-2.8946-0.5903-0.6855-0.3936-1.1679-0.9109-1.4472-1.552s-0.419-1.99-0.419-4.0467v-11.635l-2.5137-4e-7v-2.666h2.5137v-5.0083l3.4087-2.0566v7.0649h3.4468v2.666l-3.4468-6e-7v11.826c0 0.9775 0.0603 1.6059 0.1809 1.8852s0.3174 0.5015 0.5903 0.6665c0.273 0.1651 0.6634 0.2476 1.1712 0.2476 0.3808 0 0.8823-0.0445 1.5044-0.1333m16.713 0.5713c-1.2695 1.0791-2.4915 1.8408-3.6658 2.2851-1.1743 0.4444-2.4343 0.6665-3.78 0.6665-2.2217 0-3.9292-0.5427-5.1226-1.6281-1.1933-1.0855-1.79-2.4725-1.79-4.1609 0-0.9903 0.2253-1.8948 0.676-2.7137 0.45069-0.81884 1.041-1.4758 1.771-1.9709 0.72998-0.49512 1.552-0.86963 2.4661-1.1235 0.67286-0.17773 1.6885-0.34912 3.0469-0.51416 2.7676-0.33008 4.8052-0.72363 6.1128-1.1807 0.0127-0.46973 0.01905-0.76807 0.01905-0.89502 0-1.3965-0.32373-2.3804-0.97119-2.9517-0.87598-0.77441-2.1773-1.1616-3.9038-1.1616-1.6123 0-2.8025 0.28247-3.5706 0.84741-0.76807 0.56494-1.3362 1.5647-1.7044 2.9993l-3.3516-0.45704c0.3047-1.4346 0.80616-2.593 1.5044-3.4753 0.69824-0.88232 1.7075-1.5615 3.0278-2.0376 1.3203-0.47608 2.8501-0.71411 4.5894-0.71411 1.7266 0 3.1294 0.20312 4.2085 0.60937s1.8726 0.91724 2.3804 1.533c0.50781 0.61572 0.86328 1.3933 1.0664 2.3328 0.11425 0.58399 0.17138 1.6377 0.17138 3.1611v4.5703c0 3.1865 0.073 5.2019 0.219 6.0461 0.14599 0.8443 0.43481 1.6536 0.86645 2.428h-3.5801c-0.35547-0.7109-0.58398-1.5425-0.68554-2.4946m-0.28565-7.6553c-1.2441 0.50781-3.1103 0.93945-5.5986 1.2949-1.4092 0.20312-2.4058 0.43164-2.9898 0.68555-0.58398 0.2539-1.0347 0.62524-1.352 1.114-0.31738 0.4887-0.47607 1.0315-0.47607 1.6282 0 0.914 0.34594 1.6757 1.0378 2.2851 0.69189 0.6094 1.7043 0.9141 3.0374 0.9141 1.3203 0 2.4946-0.2888 3.523-0.8665 1.0283-0.5776 1.7837-1.3679 2.2661-2.3708 0.36816-0.7744 0.55224-1.917 0.55224-3.4278v-1.2568m9.0889 10.15v-20.224h3.085v2.8755c1.4853-2.2217 3.6308-3.3325 6.4365-3.3325 1.2187 0 2.3391 0.21899 3.3611 0.65698 1.0219 0.43799 1.7868 1.0124 2.2946 1.7234 0.5079 0.71094 0.8633 1.5552 1.0665 2.5327 0.1269 0.63476 0.1904 1.7456 0.1904 3.3325v12.435h-3.4278v-12.302c0-1.3965-0.1333-2.4407-0.3999-3.1326-0.2666-0.6919-0.7395-1.2441-1.4187-1.6567-0.6792-0.4126-1.4758-0.6189-2.3898-0.6189-1.46-1e-6 -2.72 0.46338-3.7801 1.3901-1.06 0.92676-1.5901 2.6851-1.5901 5.2749v11.045h-3.4277m35.197-7.4077 3.3706 0.438c-0.3682 2.3232-1.3108 4.1418-2.8279 5.4558s-3.3801 1.9709-5.5891 1.9709c-2.7676 0-4.9924-0.9045-6.6746-2.7136-1.6821-1.8091-2.5232-4.4021-2.5232-7.779 0-2.1836 0.3619-4.0942 1.0855-5.7319 0.7236-1.6377 1.8249-2.866 3.3039-3.6848 1.479-0.81884 3.0882-1.2283 4.8274-1.2283 2.1963 0 3.9927 0.55542 5.3892 1.6663 1.3965 1.1108 2.2915 2.6882 2.6851 4.7322l-3.3326 0.51416c-0.3173-1.3584-0.8791-2.3804-1.6853-3.0659-0.8061-0.68555-1.7805-1.0283-2.9231-1.0283-1.7265 0-3.1294 0.6189-4.2085 1.8567-1.0791 1.2378-1.6186 3.196-1.6186 5.8748 0 2.7168 0.5205 4.691 1.5615 5.9224 1.041 1.2315 2.3994 1.8472 4.0752 1.8472 1.3457 0 2.4692-0.4126 3.3706-1.2378s1.4727-2.0947 1.7139-3.8086m20.647 0.895 3.542 0.438c-0.5586 2.0693-1.5932 3.6753-3.104 4.8179-1.5107 1.1426-3.4404 1.7138-5.789 1.7138-2.958 0-5.3035-0.9108-7.0364-2.7326s-2.5994-4.3767-2.5994-7.6648c0-3.4023 0.876-6.043 2.628-7.9219 1.7519-1.8789 4.0244-2.8184 6.8173-2.8184 2.7041 0 4.9131 0.92041 6.627 2.7612 1.7139 1.8408 2.5708 4.4307 2.5708 7.7695 0 0.20312-0.0064 0.50781-0.0191 0.91406h-15.082c0.127 2.2216 0.7554 3.9228 1.8853 5.1035 1.1298 1.1806 2.539 1.771 4.2275 1.771 1.2568 0 2.3296-0.3301 3.2183-0.9903 0.8886-0.6601 1.5932-1.7138 2.1137-3.1611m-11.254-5.5415h11.292c-0.1523-1.7012-0.584-2.977-1.2949-3.8276-1.0918-1.3203-2.5073-1.9805-4.2466-1.9805-1.5742-1e-6 -2.8977 0.52686-3.9704 1.5806-1.0728 1.0537-1.6663 2.4629-1.7806 4.2275" fill-rule="evenodd"/></g></g></svg>'>
    <ul>
        <li>customLineStyle($geometry,'45 30,45 0,45 -30,45 0') -> zig-zag line</li>
    </ul>
    


    Use smooth function to create wavelines:<br/><br/>
    Example:
    <ul><li>smooth(customLineStyle( $geometry,'45 30,45 0,45 -30,45 0'),5)</li></ul>
    """
    rings = None
    if geom.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineString:
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(createCustomLine(geom.asPolyline(),param))
    elif geom.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.MultiLineString:
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY([createCustomLine(line,param) for line in geom.asMultiPolyline()])
    elif geom.wkbType() in [QgsWkbTypes.Polygon,QgsWkbTypes.MultiPolygon]:
        geom = createCustomPolygon(geom,param)
      
    return geom
```

Comment: Can you please add some screenshots on where pasting the code and how it shall work.

Comment: also you declare the variable 'd' twice. maybe declare the second 'd' as a new variable.

Comment: @Taras: added a screenshot to my original question to make it a bit clearer

Comment: Thank you @christoph

Comment: When I try use the function I always get an error: Eval Error: float division by zero. Any hints. thanks

Comment: changed the CRS geographic to projected, not it works fine, thanks!

Comment: Sometimes problems solve themselves. Well done!

Comment: Did not unterstand what I have to do exactly to fix the "float division by zero"-error (as commented above). In my case layer and project crs both have the crs 25832. Any hints @christoph or @user16032.?

Comment: my problem was solved when i changed the geographic crs to a projected crs.