# Styling line pattern fills with geometry generator

Tags: qgis, style, geometry-generator

I try to style line pattern fills of polygones with the geometry-generator to get zigzag-line/wavy lines with this script [Custom QGIS linestyle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376411/custom-qgis-linestyle-expression-function-wont-work-with-multilinestrings/376503#376503) but somehow I never get the lines displayed. For lines & polygones it works great.
Edit:

Polygone with line pattern fill, "normal" lines
[image]

Change from simple line to geometry generator to style line in zigzag/wavy, line pattern disappears, no matter whether polygone or line is selected (outline just as illustration from a duplicated polygone)

[image]

What I try to get ist the zigzag/wavy style as fill pattern with the option to change "wavesize" etc. via the parameter. It is only for display/print so breaking up polygones or adding lines would be also possible, but I would prefere the elegent way @christoph did for outlines

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKLh2.jpg)

[for lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241802/drawing-wavy-wiggly-lines-in-qgis/354873#354873)

Any other solutions for wavy/zigzag-fills are welcomed. At the moment I use svg-marker-lines as workaround, but it is not very flexible.
For a other workaround I thought about generating parallel lines and clip with the polygones, but again not very flexible.

Comment: Please provide example screenshots of what you're aiming at, as well as what you attempted so far **in detail**.

Comment: Just saw your comment https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376411/custom-qgis-linestyle-expression-function-wont-work-with-multilinestrings/376503#comment662611_376503, is the issue solved?

Comment: @pathmapper: yes, for lines & polygoneoutlines it works well now, sorry for the typo.

Comment: @user16032 good question! Never thought about creating zigzag pattern fills. Unfortunately, it seams like Geometry Generators won't work with line pattern fills at all.

Answer (score 4):

Since QGIS 3.18 we have `dynamic SVG parameters` which we can use to draw wavy line pattern fills. The idea is to create dynamic SVG Bézier curves as the basis for our fills. (https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-svg-quadratic-curves/)

**bezier.svg**

```
<path d="M1,3 Q3,0  5,3 T9,3"/>
```

[image]

```html
<svg width="1000" height="600" viewBox="0 0 10 6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="param(path)" style="stroke:param(outline);stroke-width:param(outline-width);fill:transparent"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

We need to fiddle around with `marker width`,`marker interval` and `line pattern spacing` to get a reasonable result:

[image]

If we use a global variable (i.e. `@path`) instead of the expression, we can change the curve dynamically without selecting a different SVG.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't worry about using symbology styles instead of the geometry generator, you can use a marker line with a 45 degrees rotation, duplicated at 135 degrees rotation with an offset.

[image: 1]

Following is the symbology exported to a QGIS style .qml file, if you want to save it and import to your layer:

```
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis styleCategories="Symbology" version="3.18.3-Zürich">
  <renderer-v2 type="singleSymbol" symbollevels="0" forceraster="0" enableorderby="0">
    <symbols>
      <symbol type="fill" alpha="1" clip_to_extent="1" force_rhr="0" name="0">
        <data_defined_properties>
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
            <Option name="properties"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
          </Option>
        </data_defined_properties>
        <layer enabled="1" class="LinePatternFill" pass="0" locked="0">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" value="45" name="angle"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="0,0,0,255" name="color"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="5" name="distance"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="distance_map_unit_scale"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="distance_unit"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="0.5" name="line_width"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="line_width_map_unit_scale"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="line_width_unit"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="0" name="offset"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="offset_map_unit_scale"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="offset_unit"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="outline_width_map_unit_scale"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="outline_width_unit"/>
          </Option>
          <prop k="angle" v="45"/>
          <prop k="color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
          <prop k="distance" v="5"/>
          <prop k="distance_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="distance_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="line_width" v="0.5"/>
          <prop k="line_width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="line_width_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
          <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
          <data_defined_properties>
            <Option type="Map">
              <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
              <Option name="properties"/>
              <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
            </Option>
          </data_defined_properties>
          <symbol type="line" alpha="1" clip_to_extent="1" force_rhr="0" name="@0@0">
            <data_defined_properties>
              <Option type="Map">
                <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
                <Option name="properties"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
              </Option>
            </data_defined_properties>
            <layer enabled="1" class="MarkerLine" pass="0" locked="0">
              <Option type="Map">
                <Option type="QString" value="4" name="average_angle_length"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="average_angle_map_unit_scale"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="average_angle_unit"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="5" name="interval"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="interval_map_unit_scale"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="interval_unit"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="5.55112e-17" name="offset"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="2.5" name="offset_along_line"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="offset_along_line_map_unit_scale"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="offset_along_line_unit"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="offset_map_unit_scale"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="offset_unit"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="interval" name="placement"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="0" name="ring_filter"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="1" name="rotate"/>
              </Option>
              <prop k="average_angle_length" v="4"/>
              <prop k="average_angle_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="average_angle_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="interval" v="5"/>
              <prop k="interval_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="interval_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="offset" v="5.55112e-17"/>
              <prop k="offset_along_line" v="2.5"/>
              <prop k="offset_along_line_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_along_line_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="placement" v="interval"/>
              <prop k="ring_filter" v="0"/>
              <prop k="rotate" v="1"/>
              <data_defined_properties>
                <Option type="Map">
                  <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
                  <Option name="properties"/>
                  <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
                </Option>
              </data_defined_properties>
              <symbol type="marker" alpha="1" clip_to_extent="1" force_rhr="0" name="@@0@0@0">
                <data_defined_properties>
                  <Option type="Map">
                    <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
                    <Option name="properties"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
                  </Option>
                </data_defined_properties>
                <layer enabled="1" class="SimpleMarker" pass="0" locked="0">
                  <Option type="Map">
                    <Option type="QString" value="135" name="angle"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="255,0,0,255" name="color"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="1" name="horizontal_anchor_point"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="miter" name="joinstyle"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="line" name="name"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="0,0" name="offset"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="offset_map_unit_scale"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="offset_unit"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="0,0,0,255" name="outline_color"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="solid" name="outline_style"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="0.4" name="outline_width"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="outline_width_map_unit_scale"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="outline_width_unit"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="diameter" name="scale_method"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="3" name="size"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="size_map_unit_scale"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="size_unit"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="1" name="vertical_anchor_point"/>
                  </Option>
                  <prop k="angle" v="135"/>
                  <prop k="color" v="255,0,0,255"/>
                  <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
                  <prop k="joinstyle" v="miter"/>
                  <prop k="name" v="line"/>
                  <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
                  <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
                  <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
                  <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
                  <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
                  <prop k="outline_width" v="0.4"/>
                  <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
                  <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
                  <prop k="scale_method" v="diameter"/>
                  <prop k="size" v="3"/>
                  <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
                  <prop k="size_unit" v="MM"/>
                  <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
                  <data_defined_properties>
                    <Option type="Map">
                      <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
                      <Option name="properties"/>
                      <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
                    </Option>
                  </data_defined_properties>
                </layer>
              </symbol>
            </layer>
            <layer enabled="1" class="MarkerLine" pass="0" locked="0">
              <Option type="Map">
                <Option type="QString" value="4" name="average_angle_length"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="average_angle_map_unit_scale"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="average_angle_unit"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="5" name="interval"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="interval_map_unit_scale"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="interval_unit"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="0" name="offset"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="0" name="offset_along_line"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="offset_along_line_map_unit_scale"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="offset_along_line_unit"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="offset_map_unit_scale"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="offset_unit"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="interval" name="placement"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="0" name="ring_filter"/>
                <Option type="QString" value="1" name="rotate"/>
              </Option>
              <prop k="average_angle_length" v="4"/>
              <prop k="average_angle_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="average_angle_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="interval" v="5"/>
              <prop k="interval_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="interval_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="offset" v="0"/>
              <prop k="offset_along_line" v="0"/>
              <prop k="offset_along_line_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_along_line_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
              <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
              <prop k="placement" v="interval"/>
              <prop k="ring_filter" v="0"/>
              <prop k="rotate" v="1"/>
              <data_defined_properties>
                <Option type="Map">
                  <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
                  <Option name="properties"/>
                  <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
                </Option>
              </data_defined_properties>
              <symbol type="marker" alpha="1" clip_to_extent="1" force_rhr="0" name="@@0@0@1">
                <data_defined_properties>
                  <Option type="Map">
                    <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
                    <Option name="properties"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
                  </Option>
                </data_defined_properties>
                <layer enabled="1" class="SimpleMarker" pass="0" locked="0">
                  <Option type="Map">
                    <Option type="QString" value="45" name="angle"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="255,0,0,255" name="color"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="1" name="horizontal_anchor_point"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="miter" name="joinstyle"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="line" name="name"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="0,0" name="offset"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="offset_map_unit_scale"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="offset_unit"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="0,0,0,255" name="outline_color"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="solid" name="outline_style"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="0.4" name="outline_width"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="outline_width_map_unit_scale"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="outline_width_unit"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="diameter" name="scale_method"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="3" name="size"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="size_map_unit_scale"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="size_unit"/>
                    <Option type="QString" value="1" name="vertical_anchor_point"/>
                  </Option>
                  <prop k="angle" v="45"/>
                  <prop k="color" v="255,0,0,255"/>
                  <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
                  <prop k="joinstyle" v="miter"/>
                  <prop k="name" v="line"/>
                  <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
                  <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
                  <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
                  <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
                  <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
                  <prop k="outline_width" v="0.4"/>
                  <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
                  <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
                  <prop k="scale_method" v="diameter"/>
                  <prop k="size" v="3"/>
                  <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
                  <prop k="size_unit" v="MM"/>
                  <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
                  <data_defined_properties>
                    <Option type="Map">
                      <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
                      <Option name="properties"/>
                      <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
                    </Option>
                  </data_defined_properties>
                </layer>
              </symbol>
            </layer>
          </symbol>
        </layer>
        <layer enabled="1" class="SimpleFill" pass="0" locked="0">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="border_width_map_unit_scale"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="0,0,255,255" name="color"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="bevel" name="joinstyle"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="0,0" name="offset"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0" name="offset_map_unit_scale"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="offset_unit"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="35,35,35,255" name="outline_color"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="solid" name="outline_style"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="0.26" name="outline_width"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="MM" name="outline_width_unit"/>
            <Option type="QString" value="no" name="style"/>
          </Option>
          <prop k="border_width_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="color" v="0,0,255,255"/>
          <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
          <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="3x:0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="outline_color" v="35,35,35,255"/>
          <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
          <prop k="outline_width" v="0.26"/>
          <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="style" v="no"/>
          <data_defined_properties>
            <Option type="Map">
              <Option type="QString" value="" name="name"/>
              <Option name="properties"/>
              <Option type="QString" value="collection" name="type"/>
            </Option>
          </data_defined_properties>
        </layer>
      </symbol>
    </symbols>
    <rotation/>
    <sizescale/>
  </renderer-v2>
  <blendMode>0</blendMode>
  <featureBlendMode>0</featureBlendMode>
  <layerGeometryType>2</layerGeometryType>
</qgis>
```

Comment: thanks for your help! Your solution is similar to what I meant with point pattern svg fill, but much more elegant! Still missing the options with @christoph solutions for lines. A very undervalued post imho.

Comment: thanks @user16032 for giving me credit. Looks like there‘s not so much need for custom line styles in QGIS ;-)  Did it for our geologists… and they are happy now.