# How to use QGIS desktop Python code functionality in QGIS Cloud?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-web-client

I have made QGIS map with different layers and upload my map on QGIS cloud.

I have add some functionality like click function and drilldown functionality by Python code in QGIS Desktop. but these functionality is not showing up in QGIS Cloud.

QGIS Cloud is only showing first layer and not showing rest of layers.

How can use my Python functionality code in QGIS Cloud and nake drilldown and click functionality on different layers in QGIS Cloud?

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by "functionnality by python code" Can you share your code or what it does ? Maybe it's covered by native QGIS expressions.

Comment: @etrimaille code is long to upload or paste. But can you please tell how to use QGIS python console code in my GIS or QGIS Cloud?

Comment: "Python code" in QGIS is very vague. It could be custom macro, Processing script, Processing model, custom Python expression ... You need to specify what does your code approximately etc ... But anyway, if you are using QGIS cloud instance, I'm 99.9% sure it's not possible to have custom Python. If you have your own server, then more things are possible like for instance : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355319/register-custom-python-function-in-qgis-server-3-10 or running QGIS WPS Server to run Python Processing script etc ...